# finding order of a permutation of some tricky order

Tags: group-theory

If $\beta \in S_{7}$ and $|\beta^{3}|=7$, prove that the order of $\beta =7$.
All that I can deduced is that $\beta^{3}$ has a cycle of length 7 and that every permutation $\beta$ in $S_{7}$ can be expressed as a product of 2-cycles.

This question is so finicky I don''t even know how to approach it.
Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you raise an element of a group to the power which is relative prime to its order, the order of the result is not changed. If you however raise it to the power that is not relatively prime to its order, the order is reduced by the GCD of the power and the order. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: $|\beta|$ could only be $7$ or $21$, but $S_7$ has no elements of order $21$.

Comment: @DerekHolt How did you arrived at 7 or 21? There are certainly more orders than 7 and 21 for elements in S7

Comment: @Mathematicing Since $|\beta^3|=7$, this means $\beta^{21} = id$. Since $21=1\cdot3\cdot7$, the only possible orders for $\beta$ are $7$ and $21$ (we know it cannot be $3$ or $1$). Thinking about disjoint cycles, can you prove that no element of order 21 exists in $S_7$?

Comment: Yes, it is easy to show that no elements of order 21 exists in $S_{7}$. One can begin by noting that the elements in $S_{7}$ 
has element of possibly 1 cycle of length 7, 1 cycle of length 6 and 1 cycle of length 1, 1 cycle of length 5 and 1 cycle of length 2. Proceeding in this manner, one note that using the LCM to determine the order of elements in $S_{7}$, no element of order 21 exists.@SantanaAfton

Comment: @SantanaAfton Could you explain why no order of 3 and 1 exists? I'm unsure if my understanding that no order of 3 and 1 exists is valid.

Comment: We know that $|\beta|\ne1,3$ since $\beta^3$ is not the identity (it has order $7$).

Comment: That works too. I was using a different argument.

Comment: @SantanaAfton This seems to be one of those question where I can make the leapt to the final answer but having a rather tedious time filling the details. 
The permutation $\beta$ has order 21. By the theorem relating the order and length of the permutation,
$\beta$ must have order 21=LCM(1,3,7) or LCM(3,7) or LCM(21,1) or LCM(7,21) for these are the possible length of the disjoint cycles for $\beta$ for which the order of $\beta$ is 21.
I cannot be sure how this fits.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I think a full explanation would be appropriate. To be honest, I am having a hard time following your argument above. I will give an upvote if you choose to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my comment expanded. Firstly, given $|\beta^3| = 7$, we have $\beta^{21}=1$. So $|\beta$| divides $21$. But if $|\beta| = 1$ or $3$, then $|\beta^3|=1$, which is false, so $|\beta| = 7$ or $21$.

So if we can prove that $S_7$ has no element of order $21$, then we will have proved that $|\beta| = 7$. Every permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles, and the order of that permutation is equal to the LCM of the lengths of those cycles. For example $(1,2)(3,4,5)(6,7)(8,9,10,11)$ has order $12$.

So, for a permutation to have order $21$, it must either have (at least) one cycle of length $21$, or it must have two disjoint cycles, one of length $3$ and one of length $7$. Both of these are impossible in $S_7$. In fact the smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ has an element of order $21$ is $10$.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that the order of the permutation divides 21 is key.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write $\beta$ as the product of disjoint cycles. How does the order of $\beta$ relate to the length of the cycles? If $\beta$ is not a $7$-cycle, can $\beta^n$ be a $7$-cycle?

Comment: $\beta$ can be expressed as a product of 2-cycles by theorem. 
So, we can stipulate that $\beta$ can be written as a disjoint cycle. 
The order of the permutation $\beta$ is the least common multiple of the lengths of its cycle.
What am I missing?  Am I suppose to approach this indirectly via contra positivity?

Comment: Since its order is the LCM of the lengths of the disjoint cycles, when will that LCM be 7?

Comment: It would be 7 IFF it has one cycle of length 7. I understand this but unable to relate this to the fact that the order of $\beta^{3}$=7.

Comment: Consider a product of two disjoint cycles $\pi=(a_1, \ldots, a_m)(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$. In any power of $\pi$, will there be a cycle containing some $a_ib_j$?

Comment: The possible lengths of the disjoint cycles of $\beta$ is 1,3,7 or 1,21, or 7,21, or 3,7 am I right?
For these are the only cycle lengths for which the LCM yields 21.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with what we know about $\beta$ from what we're given. The note that $|\beta^3|=7$ tells us two facts:

- Since the order is $7$ and not $1$, we know neither $\beta$ nor $\beta^3$ are the identity.
- We know that $id=(\beta^3)^7=\beta^{21}$, so the order of $\beta$ must divide $21$.

The divisors of $21$ are $1,3,7$, and $21$. The first bullet tells us that $1$ and $3$ are not an option. By looking at the disjoint cycles of $\beta$, we can show (as you correctly did in the comments above) that $\beta$ cannot have order $21$. Hence, the only divisor of $21$ left is $7$, proving that $|\beta|=7$.